# Capitalization of Titles and Headers

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, indexing, capitalization

I'm attempting to capitalize certain titles or headings in my LaTeX file. Specifically, if I want to use `\printindex`, `\listoffigures`, or `\listoftables` the title heading on each of these will be "Index", "List of Figures", or "List of Tables" respectively. Is there anyway to capitalize these to produce "INDEX", "LIST OF FIGURES", or "LIST OF TABLES"? Any input would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just put this in the preamble:

```
\renewcommand{\indexname}{INDEX}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{LIST OF FIGURES}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{LIST OF TABLES}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use, e.g., the [titlesec](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package and its `uppercase` option. Note that this method will affect the headings proper, but not running headers or ToC entries -- if you want these captitalized, too, use egreg's solution.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[uppercase]{titlesec}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{FOO}

\begin{theindex}
(A fake index entry)
\end{theindex}

\end{document}
```